# Destroyed draw rectangles inside a Panel in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

In VB.Net, i have a form and a Panel. So basically, when i run the project, I can scroll down, meaning my form is a lot taller than the usual due to the Panel. I can draw rectangles and lines in perfect position, but when I scroll down my form during runtime,
the rectangles are destroyed. It's like a chaos of rectangles and lines appearing out of order. It seems to be confused of where to maintain those rectangles and lines after i scrolled down during runtime. Is it due to the the values of the points that I used? Is is about absolute positioning of points? How can I solve this?

```
Private Sub Form2_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
    ' Create pen. 
    Dim blackPen As New Pen(Color.Black, 1)
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 14, 220, 726, 30)
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 14, 250, 726, 45)
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, 143, 250, 143, 295)
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, 279, 250, 279, 295)
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, 377, 250, 377, 295)
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, 502, 250, 502, 295)
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, 14, 295, 14, 325)
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, 740, 295, 740, 325)
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 14, 325, 726, 40)
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 14, 365, 726, 37)
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 14, 402, 726, 32)
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 14, 434, 726, 32)
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 14, 466, 726, 32)
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 14, 498, 726, 32)
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 14, 530, 726, 32)
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 14, 562, 726, 32)
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 14, 594, 726, 50)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thats because the locations has changed for your rectangles, you need to repaint these rectangles again.

Answer (score 0):

Paint the graphics to a bitmap and it will not mess it up.

```
Private Sub Form2_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
 PaintTheForm()
End Sub
Private Sub PaintTheForm()
 Dim bmp As New Bitmap(Me.Width, Me.Height)
 Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
  Dim blackPen As New Pen(Color.Black, 1)
  g.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 14, 220, 726, 30)
  g.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 14, 250, 726, 45)
  g.DrawLine(blackPen, 143, 250, 143, 295)
  g.DrawLine(blackPen, 279, 250, 279, 295)
  g.DrawLine(blackPen, 377, 250, 377, 295)
  g.DrawLine(blackPen, 502, 250, 502, 295)
  g.DrawLine(blackPen, 14, 295, 14, 325)
  g.DrawLine(blackPen, 740, 295, 740, 325)
  g.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 14, 325, 726, 40)
  g.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 14, 365, 726, 37)
  g.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 14, 402, 726, 32)
  g.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 14, 434, 726, 32)
  g.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 14, 466, 726, 32)
  g.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 14, 498, 726, 32)
  g.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 14, 530, 726, 32)
  g.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 14, 562, 726, 32)
  g.DrawRectangle(blackPen, 14, 594, 726, 50)
  Me.BackgroundImage = bmp
 End Using
End Sub
```